# Issue with understanding concept behind wp_localize_script function

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, localization

I'm currently teaching myself how to use AJAX with Wordpress. To get the AJAX-admin URL I use the wp_localize_script function that Wordpress provides (https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) to hand over the URL to my Javascript File in array. In my JS file I can then access the array that I "attached" to my JS. While this works just fine, I have trouble understanding the concept behind it.

```
<?php

// Register the script
wp_register_script( 'some_handle', 'path/to/myscript.js' );

// Localize the script with new data
$translation_array = array(
    'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
);
wp_localize_script( 'some_handle', 'object_name', $translation_array );

// Enqueued script with localized data.
wp_enqueue_script( 'some_handle' );
```

The data can then be accessed in the JS file like this

```
<script>
// alerts 'Some string to translate'
alert( object_name.ajax_url);
</script>
```

How is it possible that I can access an array in my Javascript that I never explicitly defined in the Javascript file? How can the PHP just "attach" the Array to my Javascript, without it being formally written out inside the file?

I guess there is a basic concept about JS that I don't understand yet, so it'd be great if you could point me in a direction.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after some more research I figured it out – I was just looking at the wrong place. The data is not actually written into any specific Javascript File (or magically attached to one).

It is simply printed out in the DOM as an object inside an HTML `<script>` tag like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var ajaxUrl = {"ajaxurl":"http://*******************/admin-ajax.php"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

From here it is accessible to all the JS files.